# Allow forward slash in ng-pattern regex.

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Should be fairly straight forward. Trying to allow a forward slash in my numeric only ng-pattern for a form field (expiration date).

HTML:

```
              <input type="text" id="expiration-date" name="expirationDate"
                data-ng-model="register.expirationDate"
                data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"
                data-ng-minlength="7"
                maxlength="7"
                placeholder="MM/YYYY"
                data-ui-mask="99/9999"
                data-ng-required="true">
```

Trying to allow the forward slash in the model, otherwise the model never updates because it only accept numbers. I have very little knowledge with regex.

Comment: Explanation for the downvote? Or just mid day trolling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a forward slash into the character class.

```
  <input type="text" id="expiration-date" name="expirationDate"
    data-ng-model="register.expirationDate"
    data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9\/]+$/"
    data-ng-minlength="7"
    maxlength="7"
    placeholder="MM/YYYY"
    data-ui-mask="99/9999"
    data-ng-required="true">
```

Comment: That worked! I'll mark it as correct when the cooldown ends. Thanks!

Comment: Does it support backward slash?

Comment: @forgottofly no it won't, try `data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9\/\\]+$/"`, if you want so.

Comment: Can you pls explain how it works?I'm confused with \/\\ and +$/  part..

Comment: `^` used to match start of a line, `[0-9\/\\]+` would match any num from 0 to 9 or `\/` a forward slash or `\\` a backward slash, one or more times (`+`).. starting `/` and ending `/` are regex delimiters.

Comment: Thanks :-) Great help

Comment: @AvinashRaj  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395451/ng-pattern-that-allows-decimal-ratios