# ng-pattern that allows decimal ratios

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I'm having an `ng-pattern` that validates for a ration like 4:6 as shown below:

```
ng-pattern="/^(\d+):(\d+)$/"
```

I want also to validate if decimal numbers are entered as rations along with the above validation.Example :5.4:7.1
I trid by giving `ng-pattern` as

```
ng-pattern="/^(\.[0-9]{1,2}+):(\.[0-9]{1,2}+)$/"
```

But not triggering the validation.Please suggest me where I'm going wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `^(\.[0-9]{1,2}+):(\.[0-9]{1,2}+)$` is not a valid pattern in JS as the limiting quantifier `{min,max}` cannot be followed with `+` (no possessive quantifiers are supported by JS regex engine). Even if you remove the pluses and use `^(\.[0-9]{1,2}):(\.[0-9]{1,2})$`, the pattern would match strings like `.1:.3` or `.34:.45` and would not allow `3:45` (dots would be obligatory).

Use the following regex if you want to allow values like `.5`:

```
ng-pattern="/^\d*\.?\d+:\d*\.?\d+$/"
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZttdn/2).

Alternatively, you may use

```
ng-pattern="/^(\d+\.)?\d+:(\d+\.)?\d+$/"
```

to only allow numbers with non-empty integer part. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/noOyN9/1).